# translate motto into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto, preposition

How would you translate this motto into Latin: “near side or off side, but always centered”.
This refers to the side a lady rides on her horse in a side saddle: near side is with both legs on the left side of the horse, off side is with both legs to the right side of the horse. And whether you ride to one side or the other, you always have to sit straight/ balanced in the middle/center. It would also refer to the second meaning of “centered”, where we refer to a balanced and centered character in a person.
I am looking for a very resumed, catchy expression, something that would go on a crest for example.
I found something like “hoc aut hinc, medium semper “, but it’s been sooo long since I studied Latin that I have no clue whatsoever if this is grammatically correct. And probably there’s way better words than “medium” too…
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This translation might not be easy to give. I can't really tell if Romans actually rode sideways. I don't know if any of their clothes, even the toga or stola, made it necessary to ride sideways.

Comment: Hello! Yes indeed, side saddle was definitely NOT in vogue in Roman times, hehe. Riding as a whole wasn’t too evolved really. 
I was thinking more about something in the line of “this side or that side” in Latin, as literal translations are impossible of course. That concept can easily be interpreted by a modern side saddle rider as near side/off side. Some poetic liberty is allowed! Hehe

Comment: Can you explain a little more the meaning of the motto? It would help to figure out a translation.

Comment: It’s about how it doesn’t matter wether you ride with your kegs to the left or the right, you always have to sit balanced in the center of the saddle and horse.